# Open a CSV from internet in VBA on a Mac

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook with several VBA workbooks originally written on a PC. All the code works perfectly on PC. I recently purchased a new Macbook Pro and was under the impression that with Excel 2016 all VBA came from the same codebase and should transfer seamlessly.

Anyways some of my code is opening a csv downloaded from the internet in a new workbook, copying the data into the active workbook, and closing the externally opened csv. When I run this code on a Mac I get a Run Time Error 1004 Method 'Open' of Object 'Workbooks' Failed. I've searched around and most of the answers seem to be targeting opening workbooks on the local machine and the difference in the Mac vs PC file paths, but haven't been able to figure out why opening a link from the internet won't work.

Working code from PC:

```
Sub DownloadTVALines()
sCSVLink = "http://www.oasis.oati.com/woa/docs/TVA/TVAdocs/TransmissionOutages.csv"
sfile = "TransmissionOutages.csv"
ssheet = "TVA Line Outages"

Application.Cursor = xlWait
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wnd = ActiveWindow
Sheets(ssheet).Cells.ClearContents
Workbooks.Open (sCSVLink)
Windows(sfile).Activate
ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
wnd.Activate
Sheets("TVA Line Outages").Activate
Range("A1").Activate
Sheets("TVA Line Outages").Paste
Windows(sfile).Close False

Application.Cursor = xlDefault
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to contact [Ron de Bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/whatsnew.htm),  He has the most and best VBA MAC content.  The MAC VBA integration is much better than it used to be but it is still lacking.